# How to modify jquery select2 method ($.fn.select2) using underscore _.wrap method

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have a below HTML code for select2 combobox ([pnlkr link](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y8Sml5km7LdlMq7ryYtG?p=preview))

```
<label id="label-select2Home">My Home State: </label>
<div class="select2-home" xe-field="select2Home"></div>
```

JS to initialize:

```
$( ".select2-home" ).select2({
        tokenSeparators: [",", " "],
        allowClear: true,
        placeholder: "Select a state",
        data: stateData
});
```

**WHAT I HAVE TO DO:**

i have to find the label nearby and should change the text to "TEST LABEL".

I am trying to do the above with

```
$.fn.select2 = _.wrap($.fn.select2, function changeLabel(org) {
  // Replace the nearby label text with "TEST LABEL"
});
```

I am not able to do with

```
 // Replace the nearby label text with "TEST LABEL"
var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);  // use Array.slice function to copy the arguments array from 1-end, without 'org'
        return org.apply( this, args );
```

Its giving me the error, How to invoke .apply method to manipulate the select2 and change the label text.

Please see [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y8Sml5km7LdlMq7ryYtG?p=preview) for the above example

Comment: Can you please create `jsfiddle` of your code?

Comment: Can you see my EDIT, http://plnkr.co/edit/Y8Sml5km7LdlMq7ryYtG?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the `_.wrap` function is slightly broken in that it completely wipes out the old value of `$.fn.select2`.  In doing so, it wipes out `$.fn.select2.defaults`, which messes up the plugin.

To account for this, you can do something like:

```
$.fn.select2 = _.wrap($.fn.select2, function changeLabel(org) {
    // Replace the nearby label text with "TEST LABEL"

    $.fn.select2.defaults = org.defaults;
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    return org.apply(this, args);
});
```